# need some ideas on how to solve this question that deals with recursion and loops

Tags: python

I am studying for an exam in college and I am trying to solve this problem where there is a company 'Fruits Storage' that provides storage services to his clients.
The company wants to know the number of tons of fruits stored in its warehouses. I have to develop a function that receives a dictionary with the fruit stock. ( the exercise gives us the dictionary in case). Each warehouse may contain branches and sub branches. We have to add up all tons of fruit in the all the warehouses and print the answer.

here is the dictionary given:

```
warehouses = { 
    "Warehouse Lisboa": [
        { "name": "apples", "tons": 4},
        { "name": "oranges", "tons": 10},
        { "name": "lemons", "tons": 50}
    ], 
    "Warehouse Cascais": { 
            "Branch 1": [
                { "name": "apples", "tons": 10},
                { "name": "oranges", "tons": 24}
            ],
            "Branch 2": [
                { "name": "apples", "tons": 16},
                { "name": "oranges", "tons": 8}
            ]
    }, 
    "Warehouse Oeiras": { 
            
            "Branch 1": { 
                "Sub Branch 1":{
                    "Sub sub Branch 1": [
                        { "name": "lemons", "tons": 10}       
                    ]
                } 
            },
```

as you can see some warehouse dont have branches, some have multiple so we should use a loop and recursion.

This is what I have come up with so far.

```
def stock_fruits(warehouses):
    tons1 = 0
    for key in warehouses:
        if type(warehouses[key]) == list:
            tons1 += warehouses["tons"]
        
        else:
            stock_fruits(warehouses[key])
        
    return tons1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over all collection's items:

```
warehouses = {
    "Warehouse Lisboa": [{
        "name": "apples",
        "tons": 4
    }, {
        "name": "oranges",
        "tons": 10
    }, {
        "name": "lemons",
        "tons": 50
    }],
    "Warehouse Cascais": {
        "Branch 1": [{
            "name": "apples",
            "tons": 10
        }, {
            "name": "oranges",
            "tons": 24
        }],
        "Branch 2": [{
            "name": "apples",
            "tons": 16
        }, {
            "name": "oranges",
            "tons": 8
        }]
    },
    "Warehouse Oeiras": {
        "Branch 1": {
            "Sub Branch 1": {
                "Sub sub Branch 1": [{
                    "name": "lemons",
                    "tons": 10
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}


def findFruits(obj, name, result):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            result = findFruits(item, name, result)
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        if "name" in obj and obj['name'] == name:
            result += obj['tons']
        else:
            for k, v in obj.items():
                result = findFruits(v, name, result)
    return result


for fruit in ('apples', "lemons"):
    res = 0
    res = findFruits(warehouses, fruit, res)
    print(res)
```

Out:

```
30
60
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
def fruit_stock(warehouses, fruit):
    total = 0
    for warehouse in warehouses:
        if type(warehouses[warehouse]) == list:
            for item in warehouses[warehouse]:
                if item['name'] == fruit:
                    total += item['tons']
        else:
            total += fruit_stock(warehouses[warehouse], fruit)
    return total
```

```
fruit_stock(warehouses1, 'lemons')
# 60
```

And if you not need to check any specific fruit:

```
def fruit_stock(warehouses):
    total = 0
    for warehouse in warehouses:
        if type(warehouses[warehouse]) == list:
            for item in warehouses[warehouse]:
                total += item['tons']
        else:
            total += fruit_stock(warehouses[warehouse])
    return total

fruit_stock(warehouses1)
# 132
```